# Measure to not be affected by filters/slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to use last year data to set the target for current year in a target visual.

```
2017(Static) 2018(Dynamic)
```

If I have two measures like above, and need to show them in the same visual, is it possible in the DAX or measure options for it not to be affected by a slicer/filter? So that 2017 would not get it's values changed but 2018 would.

I've tried creating the 2017 target in a calculated column, but even with the same DAX formula the calculated column and measure will be different, which I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap your current measure formula for 2017 in a CALCULATE function, using the ALLNOBLANKROW formula in the 2nd **Filter** parameter.  The table or column inside the ALLNOBLANKROW formula would be whatever you want to "not be affected".

It would look something like:

```
2017 = CALCULATE ( <<prior 2017 formula>> , ALLNOBLANKROW ( 'My Table 1' ) )
```